# Different aggregate root for insert and delete

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Imagine we have the following `aggregate root`:

```
public class Resource
{
   public IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules {get;private set;}
   ...
}
```

When we want to add a new `schedule` we need to ensure that it will not collide with an existing one. This translates to having the`aggregate root` ensuring this invariant on the `resource.AddSchedule(schedule)` method.

On the other side, the deletion of a `schedule` has no invariants. If we use the `Resource aggregate root` to delete a `schedule`, we need to previously load all the `schedules` to delete just one.

Based on this, should we promote the `Schedule` to an `aggregate root`, load just the `schedule` we need and then delete it? Or should we keep using the previous `aggregate root`?

Answer (score 1):

> When we want to add a new schedule we need to ensure that it will not collide with an existing one.

The general term for what you are trying to achieve here is [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).

If you need absolute assurance that there are no conflicting entries in the set, sometimes called "immediate consistency", then you must have assurance that the entries aren't being changed concurrently with your check.  That means that the values that you care about in your check *must* be part of the aggregate checking them -- we need that to be sure that the answers aren't changing underneath us.

The more common case is that "best effort" is good enough, and there are protocols available for resolving conflicts that slip through the cracks.  In that case, you can often treat the set as a list of identifiers, rather than a list of values.  So the details can go off to live in the Schedule aggregate, and the Resource aggregate only tracks schedule membership.

There's an additional corner case -- if Schedules are values rather than entities... meaning that the details for a given schedule are immutable, then you can maybe have your cake and eat it too -- compute a unique hash for each schedule, and store the hash values in the Resource, which can later be used to look up the immutable schedule if necessary.

A big part of the work here is getting the details of the business requirements right.  In most mature business domains, conflicts happen often enough that there are protocols for resolving them.  In other words, [race conditions don't exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

On a practical level, which of the following two is more likely to be raised as a concern by your users?

- The application is too slow when we try to delete a schedule
- We would like to apply rule X when deleting schedules

Personally, I would avoid premature optimizations that might paint you into a corner in the future.

Comment: Gotcha! When doing DDD we need to modify our datatabase driven mind.

Comment: @PedroFaustino That is one of the first challenges, but once you free yourself from that shackle, you realize that everything comes down to requirements. It's easy to jump into db schema design, but that's often not where the value is.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on this, should we promote the Schedule to an aggregate root

If the `Schedule` has a life cycle of its own then it would need to be an aggregate in any event and that would slightly change your design.

However, assuming that your relationship between `Resource`->`Schedule` is the same as `Order`->`OrderItem` then you could always have the repository expose a simpler deletion for the `Schedule`:

```
public interface IResourceRepository
{
   void Add(Resource resource);
   void RemoveSchedule(Resource resource, Resource.Schedule schedule); // or some such
}
```

For an `Order` this would probably *not* work given that there *would* probably be relevant invariants.

***update***:

If your `Schedule` is an aggregate root then you would probably create that independently of, and before, the `Resource`.  The uniqueness of the `Schedule` would fall within the purview of *set validation* as mentioned by @VoiceOfUnreason.  Your `Resource` would then still require a list of references to the `Schedule` instances but those references would be either only the `Id` or some value object contain the `Id` and any other pertinent bits.  Ensuring that you don't have duplicate schedules would be an invariant enforced by the `Resource`.

In order to remove the schedule from the resource you would then be back to the first options: either load the `Resource` and remove the relevant schedule `Id` or simply delete it "directly via the repository.

There is always the hard-vs-soft delete affair and one should typically only change the status (soft-delete) as there are fewer issues.  A hard-delete of a `Schedule` would then probably either be stopped by DRI on the data store (if configured) or cascade the delete to the relevant tables.

Comment: Considering that the Schedule has a life cycle of its own and is promoted to an AR, how could I ensure that one resource cannot have two schedules at the same time?